# Angular Reactive Form not connected

Tags: angular, forms

I have  a reactive form which is not connected. Whataver I tried, I have always this error popping in the console: Form submission canceled because the form is not connected.

I have ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule imported in app.module.ts.

HTML:

```
    <form [formGroup]="creationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

        <div class="field-input">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Nom de l'agenda</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Exemple : Dr Brassard" id="name" formControlName="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Exemple : DrBrassard@gmail.com" formControlName="email">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="tel">Téléphone fixe</label>
                <input type="text" id="tel" placeholder="Exemple : 02 02 02 02 02" formControlName="tel">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="mobile">Téléphone fixe</label>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" placeholder="Exemple : 06 06 06 06 06" formControlName="mobile">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="ctiId">Couplage CTI</label>
                <input type="text" id="ctiId" placeholder="Optionnel" formControlName="ctiId">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="" formControlName="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" [routerLink]="['/agendas']" routerLinkActive="active"
            (click)="revert()" [disabled]="creationForm.pristine">Annuler</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class=" btn btn-primary" [disabled]="creationForm.invalid" [routerLink]="['/agendas']"
            routerLinkActive="active">Finaliser</button> -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="creationForm.invalid" [routerLink]="['/wizard2']"
            routerLinkActive="active">Suivant</button>
    </form>
```

TS:

```
creationForm: FormGroup;

createFormGroup() {
return new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
  email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  tel: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  mobile: new FormControl(''),
  ctiId: new FormControl(''),
  password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
})
}

constructor() {
this.creationForm = this.createFormGroup();
  }

onSubmit() {
console.log(this.creationForm);
}
```

I have tried several thing as commented every button, except one, moving things left and right but I do not see what is wrong with what I did.

Any help appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with your issue please ?

Comment: It works fine with the stackblitz example of your code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mju5nq?file=src/app/app.component.html . I have just removed the routerLink because it is invalid option with a button. if you want to redirect somewhere on form success submit , you can simply navigate in onSubmit method

Comment: Thank you, I realize that no longer after I posted the thread. I posted a response.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the router link from the submit button. It had to be included in the onSubmit() method to work.